# Internet ports: connect to personal server from work, not on port 22 or 443

Tags: sockets, ssh

Sorry for the basic question but im a complete noob on those matters.

I have a cloud server where i run a jup[yter notebook server, which normally is run on port 8888.

However when i try to connect to it from work, it doesnt work, which i suspect is due to the firewall.

I can connect from work to a regular ssh session through port 22 or 443.

However the jupyter notebook refuses to be run on those ports, probably because they are allocated already.

I tried to run [PortQry](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17148) to get the open ports on my work server (which is windows) and it reurned port 50248. I tried to have my jupyter server to listen on that one but it didnt work.

[I also tried to scan the open port of my work server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35543955/python3-5-asyncio-tcp-scanner), but i received a warning from AWS! And the few ports that were returned as seemingly opened didnt work either when i set up my jupyter notebook to listen on them.

I would like to understand:

- On my own server: How can i identify which port the jupyter server program can listen on?
- On my work machine: How can i identify which one of my own server port would be let through the firewall of my work?

Comment: This is probably more on topic on superuser.com. But anyway: since SSH is possible just create a tunnel: `ssh -L1234:127.0.0.1:8888 your-personal-server` and then access the notebook on `http://127.0.0.1:1234`. This is probably also way more secure than exposing your jupyter notebook to the dangerous internet.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use SSH local port forwarding.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding

You will open a SSH connection to your server but a local port, lets say 4444, will connect over the SSH connection and resolve to 8888 on the remote server.

With this you'd be able to open a browser locally and go to localhost:4444 and it would resolve to your remote hosted site. The command for this locally would be something like -

```
ssh -L 4444:localhost:8080 yourremoteserveraddress
```

An alternative option would be to use a SOCKS proxy via dynamic forwarding but this would involve needing to reconfigure your browser.

Always keep in mind any company policies around this type of thing. Even though 22 and 443 are open to the internet, use of them in this manner may break a policy and there is always the possibility of the company using a MITM proxy to monitor for this type of usage, specifically on 443.

Comment: Thx for your answer - and sorry for the delay. I tried to use your solution - but then i realisedthat i cannot use the following line `ssh -L 4444:localhost:8080 yourremoteserveraddress` with putty on windows, as it seems no ssh server is running on windows by default? I read few solution about cygwin, etc. but I am quite confused so rather ask here. What would be the solution if my work computer is running on windows, and i used to connect to my remote server through putty?

Comment: Is the remote server also running Windows or is it UNIX based? On Windows to use SSH as a client I recommend using Git Bash as an alternative to cygwin.

Comment: The remote is Linux.. So for that config you would recommand using Git Bash to create the local ssh server and connect to the remote?

Comment: You don't need a local SSH server if you're just attempting to forward the connections to your remote. All you're doing is using the SSH client at the command line to connect to the remote and forward ports appropriately. Yes, I would use Git Bash. It is an easier setup than stock Cygwin and functions similar to a Bash shell on UNIX.

Comment: If this answered your question please mark as answered.

Comment: If I dont need a local ssh server then Putty should be enough shouldn't it? This is what i connect with for ordinary connection and also what i am most familiar with. However  I tried following multiple putty tutorial to create such tunnel (for instance this one https://blog.devolutions.net/2017/04/how-to-configure-an-ssh-tunnel-on-putty.html) but did not managed.  It seemed to me i would need to have a "local" adress from which the port is forwarded, this needing the ssh server. Hence my confusion. Sorry i wish I can consider that question resolved but i am still confused.

Comment: Yes putty will work. The tutorial you linked is really good and describes the process but there is one caveat. For the destination you should use 127.0.0.1 for the IP since it is the local loop back on the destination server. Have you tried that? Some info about how you e configured putty would help diagnose further.

Comment: Still trying to make that work... My Putty settings are: in the "Session tab I fill the `HostName`  with `user@myremoteserverIP` and `Port` tab with `22`. Then in `Connection>SSH>Tunnel` I set `Destination` to `127.0.0.1:22`  and `Source Port` to `8888` (since the notebook listen on that port). I also ticked `Local ports accept connections from other hosts`. The putty session window starts correctly but then I can't go in my browser and reach `127.0.0.1:8888` or `127.0.0.1:22` to access my notebook. Hopefully you can still help i think I'm close. Sorry for the delayed answer